# Android dialog started from service doesn't run animations

Tags: android, animation, service, dialog

I'm trying to add a exit animation to my dialog started from a service.

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    dialog.show();
```

when I call dialog.dismiss(), the animation defined in DialogAnimation doesn't run. However, if I run the exact same code in an Activity the animation runs perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it is because the service is run at backend ,not on UI, thats why the animation does not show

Answer (score 0):

I think it is intended to be that way. I ended up making the dialog transparent, animating the dialog view, and then dismissing the dialog on animation end